# Pandas - efficient way to drop entire rows based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

Sample dataframe:

```
     id    x    y
 145421    a    b
 356005    d    a
 478279    r    f
 451426    f    p
 566927    d    k
```

I want to drop entire rows when column `id` is not equal to `356005`,`478279`,`566927`

My code:

```
df[~(df["id"].isin([356005,478279,566927]))]
```

Output I want:

```
     id    x    y
 145421    a    b
 451426    f    p
```

But after running the command Jupyter gets stuck and I had to restart several times. Is there any efficient way to write this code that compiles it instantly?

Comment: How is your dataframe size ?

Comment: 20 MB almost. 200K+ rows, 14 columns.

Comment: Is this id column different from indexes we have?

Comment: they are different. @Nancy_Tayal

Comment: This isn't even a "condition" on any columns, it's just directly **dropping by index labels**. In this case, a list of index labels. [`df.drop([...], )`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: I have edited my problem. Can you please check now? @smci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
indx = df[df["id"].apply(lambda x : x in [356005,478279,566927])]   
df.drop(index=indx.index, inplace = True)
```

or

```
indx = df.query('id in [356005,478279,566927]')
df.drop(index=indx.index, inplace = True)
```

Also, it is a better approach in case the list of 'id' to be dropped is long.

Comment: I am facing this error:
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([356005, 478279, 566927], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"

Comment: Can you please share the code you have written

Comment: You have to get the index of the rows having these column values for I'd. Here you are treating them as indexes which might not be present in the dataset.

Comment: I've edited the code and provided two different ways. Try them, if still its not working do let me know. I'll surely try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for
`df.drop(df.index[[356005,478279,566927]], inplace = True)`

Please refer to [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for more information.